# Docker timing out in Azure App Service - using Nextjs

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, next.js, azure-web-app-service

I'm using a Linux server in azure app service. Previously, I was able to deploy my nextjs app with no problems on app service, and it ran just fine. However, after another deployment the docker image suddenly kept timing out. After hours of being unable to fix this, I deleted the app on azure, recreated it, and deployed and everything worked smoothly once again. After another deployment recently, it happened again and the docker image is timing out, and I'm unable to find what the problem is. Before anyone asks, yes, nextjs is starting on port 8080 and I have the PORT and WEBSITES_PORT app variables set to 8080 in app service, you'll also see this in the logs below. My web.config and server.js files are in the root directory. I also used this tutorial to publish the nextjs app on app service: https://parveensingh.com/next-js-deployment-on-azure-app-service/

Here are the logs:
[image]

Here's my server.js:

```
const next = require("next");

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer((req, res) => {
    handle(req, res);
  }).listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(`> Ready on <http://localhost>:${port}`);
  });
});
```

Here's my web.config:

```
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     <https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config>
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit <http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx> for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^server.js\\/debug[\\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See <https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config> for a full list of options
    -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here's my package.json scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "test": "npx jest"
  },
```

Comment: Sorry about the image quality, you can open the image in another tab to see it at better resolution

Comment: I had so many different issues running an ASP.NET Core container on the Linux App Service that I migrated off to AKS instead. The Linux App Service have always seemed half baked to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try increasing the time allowed for the container to start.

Set WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT to 1800 (which is the max)

Comment: This worked for me because I actually got a log about what the real error was that was causing the timeout. I guess the older time limit wasn't long enough for that log to have occurred. I was then able to fix it and it no longer times out.

Comment: What was the real error?

Comment: @AndrewGee the getServerSideProps of a dynamic page that I had at the root directory (ex. http://localhost:300/[dynamicPage]) was being called for some reason while docker called "next start", but what I concluded is you shouldn't put dynamic pages under the root directory it should be under some subdirectory and that worked for me.